# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined. I am getting this error. Please help me figure out where I am going wrong. I am following this link(https://jsbin.com/fikosoxuki/15/edit?html,js,output)

```
<template>
    <v-card class="mb-12">
      <v-form :model='user' class="content-padding" ref='pdfInputs'> 
       <ul>
        <li v-for="(input, index) in user.inputs">
         <input type="text" v-model="input.one"> - {{ input.one }}  
         <input type="text" v-model="input.two"> - {{ input.two }}
         <button type="button" @click="deleteRow(index)">Delete</button>
        </li>
       </ul>    
       <button type="button" @click="addRow">Add more</button>
      </v-form>
    </v-card>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
  data () {
    return {
     user: {
      inputs: []
     }
    }
  }
  methods: {
    addRow() {
      this.user.inputs.push({
        one: '',
        two: ''
      })
    },
    deleteRow(index) {
      this.user.inputs.splice(index,1)
    }
  }
 }
</script>
```

Update (Error added)

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Why dont you make a codepen link of your code ?

Comment: @parthjani7 actually I was following this link (https://jsbin.com/padecawido/1/edit?html,js,output) and I modified it according to my need and it works here in this JSBin but not in my code.

Comment: if it works in the jsbin, how would someone suppose to fix it ? Anyways, try different browser.

Comment: @tony19 under the data { }

Comment: The data is set in `data`.  There's nothing wrong with the code

Comment: @tony19 I didnt get you point. Can you please explain.

Comment: @Dan Any idea what could be the issue then.

Comment: Unfortunately no.  Since it works, there's no suggestion to fix it.  Are you using Vue CLI? Is this in a .vue file?

Comment: @tony19 To add multiple user.inputs, I have add button to add as many rows a user wants to enter and save it in the database.
In addRow() method I am trying to add multiple rows as per the needs of the user requirement in inputs.

Comment: @tony19 If i dont put inputs inside the user and just does as in the updated part in the question then it works. but that is not what I want.

Comment: @Dan Please read the above comment.

Comment: @tony19 I have added every part of the code. there is nothing more to add.

Comment: @tony19 Is there a different way to push values in the array if array is inside a hash as in our case?

Comment: The code is ok, no need to look for fixes.  Maybe the `push` error comes from somewhere else in your code.  Can you paste the entire expanded Vue error from the console into your question?  Including the names of functions that generated the error.

Answer (score -1):

I don't use Vue, but do you need to create a new Vue object first?

```js
const app = new Vue({
  
  el: '#app',
  
  data: {
    user: {
      inputs: []
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    addRow() {
      this.user.inputs.push({
        one: '',
        two: ''
      })
    },
    deleteRow(index) {
      this.user.inputs.splice(index,1)
    }
  }
  
})

export default app
```

Comment: This is not the issue. I already have a Vue object created. It is just one of the page of the app.